# iteration in spark sql dataframe , getting 1st row value in first iteration and second row value in next iteration and so on

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Below is the query that will give the data and distance where distance is <=10km

```
var s=spark.sql("select date,distance from table_new where distance <=10km")
s.show()
```

this will give the output like

```
12/05/2018 | 5
13/05/2018 | 8
14/05/2018 | 18
15/05/2018 | 15
16/05/2018 | 23
---------- | --
```

i want to use first row of the dataframe s , store the date value in a variable v , in first iteration.

In next iteration it should pick the second row  , and corresponding data value to be replaced the old variable b .
 like wise so on .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at Spark "Window Functions". You may find here what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The "bad" way to do this would be to collect the dataframe using df.collect() which would return a list of Rows which you can manually iterate over each using a loop.This is bad cause it brings all the data in your driver.

The better way would be to use foreach() :

```
df.foreach(lambda x: <<your code here>>)
```

foreach() takes a lambda function as argument which iterates over each row of the dataframe without bringing all the data in the driver.But you cant use a simple local variable v inside a lambda fuction when there is overwriting involved.you can use spark accumulators for such a case.

eg: if i want to sum all the values in 2nd column

```
counter = sc.longAccumulator("counter")
df.foreach(lambda row: counter.add(row.get(1)))
```